# Error: Not trusted server certificate on Android 2.3 and older

Tags: java, android, security, ssl, https

I have certificate from GlobalSign.com ( .pem file). This file consists of 2 certificates inside (I've examined it with [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/)). Using Portecle I created BKS keystore and tried to use it in the app. I have read many different tutorials with similar topic. I've tried:

1. [Security with HTTPS and SSL](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html)
2. [One more solution](http://my-it-notes.com/2011/09/how-to-approve-ssl-certificate-on-android/)
3. [Using a Custom Certificate Trust Store on Android](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html)
4. [Android: Trusting SSL certificates](http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/)
5. others

Any solution didn't work, and I still have **"Error: Not trusted server certificate"**. Maybe You have any idea what I'm doing wrong.

P.S. There are a lot of trust-all 'solutions', but I need proper solution

Comment: which solution did you end up ? I'm trying to do the same. Could you share your solution ?

Comment: Take a look on my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19703930/1228514

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved. I have asked technical support of GlobalSign about certificates. They made some tests and took recommendations how to configure certificates on server side. Android part wasn't changed

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say exactly why you are having the issue but it sounds like you do not have the private key, the certificate you received from GlobalSign, I presume you generated the CSR? If so you will need to import the .pem file that you received back from GlobalSign the same method, if you did not generate the CSR from a private key within you BKS keystone then it would not be a trusted certificate.

That is what I think is going on anyway

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need to deal with it.